# Can't install boost to another directories

Tags: c++, linux, boost, build

I want to use only filesystem of Boost libraries. And I want the headers and the binaries in the specified directories.

So here what I did:

Download boost (filetype:tar.gz) and extract to ~/boost_1_55_0

run bootstrap.sh as follow: `./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem --libdir=~/boost155/lib --includedir=~/boost155/header/`

Detail of project-config.jam generated by bootstrap:

```
# Boost.Build Configuration
# Automatically generated by bootstrap.sh

import option ;
import feature ;

# Compiler configuration. This definition will be used unless
# you already have defined some toolsets in your user-config.jam
# file.
if ! gcc in [ feature.values <toolset> ]
{
    using gcc ; 
}

project : default-build <toolset>gcc ;

# List of --with-<library> and --without-<library>
# options. If left empty, all libraries will be built.
# Options specified on the command line completely
# override this variable.
libraries =  --with-filesystem ;

# These settings are equivivalent to corresponding command-line
# options.
option.set prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set exec-prefix : /usr/local ;
option.set libdir : ~/boost155/lib ;
option.set includedir : ~/boost155/header/ ;

# Stop on first error
option.set keep-going : false ;
```

then i run ./b2

Result of command:

```
link.jam: No such file or directory

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.



Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...patience...
...found 496 targets...


The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/esys/boost_1_55_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/esys/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib
```

As you can see, b2 don't install libraries and headers in the directories I want. I also check the folder, it's blank.

I guess the problem is a link.jam is missing. But searching the internet gives me nothing.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: A manual copy of headers and binaries will work, but I have no idea why `b2` don't copy those files into the specified folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run

```
./b2 install
```

instead of simply

```
./b2
```

(via [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html))